# Error after downgrading from Pro to Personal

Tags: entries, license, debugging

We developed a website under the trail Pro license. But now on the production server, we downgraded Craft to Personal. Since then we can't save entries and get a warning about it.

The logfile gives the next errors:

```
2016-12-07 15:23:53

Level   error
Category    exception.Craft\HttpException.404
Message Craft\HttpException in /removed-path-for-sec/craft/app/controllers/TemplatesController.php:59
2016-12-07 15:23:47

Level   error
Category    application
Message CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Upgrading to Pro solves the problem again. Could do that of course, but I'm wondering if there is an other solution :)

Comment: Have you tried deleting all caches (including data caches) after downgrading? Also, do you have any plugins installed?

Comment: Hello Mike, yes I did cache cleaning in CP and also deleted files in craft/storage/runtime/cache/

Yes we have some plugins installed.https://www.evernote.com/l/AD-3ftVzYDtItIdG8L7PhHw5CdyojICnTc8

Comment: I suspect the logs you posted are unrelated to the behavior you're seeing (the 1st is just a 404 being logged and the 2nd is a database connection issue). Try clearing out `craft/storage/runtime/logs, enable devMode, reproduce by saving an entry, then check the logs again.

Comment: A quick question as I need to downgrade from pro to personal... How did you do it? Removing the license key doesn't force it to downgrade, and I can't find anywhere in the CMS to do it either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was only able to answer this because the OP sent a support ticket to and was able to look at their database. :)

When the site was setup in Craft Pro trial mode, the content was built out with multiple locales and those locales were enabled for the sections.

Craft Personal only allows for 1 locale, so when you try to save an entry in a section that was originally setup for multiple locales under Craft Pro, you get an pretty generic "can't save entry" message.

If you go back to Craft Pro and remove the other 2 non-primary locales, the Craft Personal entry saving will work again.

Comment: Now you telling me this, it sounds very logical :) Something I will not forget next time Brad. Everything works perfect now.